# how can I add my custom validation logic to product edit/create form?

Tags: magento2, form-validation, save

I would like to add some custom logic when a product is saved to validate the data in the form before it is saved in the database. In order to achieve this I decided to create an `after` Plugin to hook in the \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Validator::validate function.

Much to my surprise, even though my function is executed correctly and it outputs the results in the logs (I can also add an error message using the MessageManagerInterface and it will show up), the result of the validation is not taken into account and the product saves normally.

I've tried returning an array like this

`['attribute_code' => 'my custom message']`

returning

`false`

How can I make the validation that I need so that the product is not saved and an error message appears?

Comment: For now I've ended up throwing an Attribute/Exception instead and it seems to handle it well but I'd like to know the correct way still.

Comment: can u post the answer here to help us